Time evolution of energy eigenstates in the Heisenberg picture
It is said that Heisenberg and Schrödinger pictures are equivalent. The way I understand this is that in the Schrödinger picture the state itself evolves in time, but in the Heisenberg picture the basis vectors themselves evolve. This is akin to active and passive transformations. Anyway, the measurable result one obtains from either picture should be identical.
I have a specific case where I seem to find a inconsistency here. Take a time independent Hamiltonian, so $\hat{H}_H(t)=\hat{H}_H(0)=\hat{H}_S$. These kind of Hamiltonians are found always when they don't contain explicit time dependence as Heisenberg EoM tells us that for a Hamiltonian $\frac{d}{dt}\hat{H}_H(t)=(\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\hat{H}_S)_H$. Now let's take an eigenvector of this operator and call it $|\psi(0)\rangle$. It has energy $E_j$. Schrödinger picture tells us that in the energy basis, this state vector has components $c_i(t)=\begin{cases} 
      0, & \text{when } i ≠ j,\\
      \mathrm{exp}\left(\frac{iE_j t}{\hbar}\right), & \text{when } i = j. 
   \end{cases}$
. In the Heisenberg picture we seem to not have this. Since $|\psi(t)\rangle = |\psi(0)\rangle$, and $\hat{H}_H=\hat{H}_H(0)$, the eigenvectors don't change, and therefore we have that $c_i(t)=\begin{cases} 
      0, & \text{when } i ≠ j,\\
      1, & \text{when } i = j. 
   \end{cases}$
.
I think this should not happen. I think you should be able to recover the same time evolution for the components of a state vector regardless if the state vector changes or the basis does. What don't I understand or have missed here?

Have you looked at what happens when you compute an expectation value (of any observable) in the Schrödinger picture for this state?

I think the expectation value calculations works well in Heisenberg picture, that is the it is always introduced. However, I am interested here in finding the set of $c_i(t)$ in the Heisenberg picture.

It is a tricky subject. Three things are however to note:

Finding the eigenvectors of an operator is ambiguous. If $|i\rangle$ is an eigenvector of an operator $\hat{o}$, then $e^{i f(t)} |i \rangle$ with an abitrary function $f$ is also an eigenvector. Which of them you choose in the step where you determine the basis that you want to develop your state in is completely abitrary.

Related to this, scalar products of states (or equivalently, as you call it, components of a state with respect to a certain basis) are not observable

You can't expect to recover the same time evolution of the states components in both pictures, because you haven't done the same things in both pictures. In detail:



Starting in the state $|\Psi_0\rangle$,
then using the Schroedinger equation to evolve the state $|\Psi(t)\rangle$
and then developing the state into eigenvectors of the operator $\hat{o}_0$,  $|i\rangle$

Or alternatively doing the same thing in the Heisenberg picture:

Starting in the state $|\Psi_0\rangle$
Using the Heisenberg equations of motion to find $\hat{o}(t)$
developing the state into eigenvectors $|i(t)\rangle$ of $\hat{o}(t)$.

Will not yield the the same results (as you have noticed yourself). They would be, if the time evolution of
\begin{align}
|\Psi(t)\rangle = \hat{U}(t)|\Psi_0\rangle
\end{align}
is the inverse of the time evolution of $|i(t)\rangle$. But in the way you proposed your question, they are not:
If you have followed through with your recipe, then you haven't obtained $|i(t)\rangle$ from $|i_0\rangle$ by applying $\hat(U)^{\dagger}$. Instead, you have started with the operator
\begin{align}
\hat{o} = \sum_i | i_0 \rangle \langle i_0 |
\end{align}
calculated
\begin{align}
\hat{U}(t)\hat{o} \hat{U}(t)^{\dagger}
\end{align}
and found the eigenvectors. These are not the same operations. As stated above, "finding the eigenvectors" introduces an ambiguity. You can already see this by noting that
\begin{align}
\hat{U}(t)\hat{o} \hat{U}(t)^{\dagger} = \hat{D}^{\dagger} \hat{U}(t)\hat{o} \hat{U}(t)^{\dagger} \hat{D}
\end{align}
will yield the same operator (with the same eigenvectors) for any diagonal Operator $\hat{D}$ that is diagonal in the basis ${|i\rangle}$. Or, equivalently, if ${|i\rangle}$ is a basis of eigenvectors, then $ \hat{D}|i\rangle$ will also yield a basis of eigenvectors. You can of course choose to find
\begin{align}
|i(t)\rangle = \hat{U}(t)^{\dagger} |i \rangle
\end{align}
This will be a valid set of eigenvectors of $\hat{o}(t)$, and it will yield the correct components that you have already found in the schroedinger picture. But this is a completely abitrary choice, that won't change anything about the possible measurement outcomes that you can obtain.

Good answer! I would note that exact value of $c_i(t)$ does affect the measurements, if $|\psi(0)\rangle$ is a superposition of $c_i(t)$. However, choosing $\hat{U}(t)$ to fix this solves the problem. Would you then say that it is physically motivated to evolve all $|i\rangle$ states by $\hat{U}(t)$?
In general if you want to find $c_i(t)$ for any observable $(\hat{A}(t))_H$, could you say -> find eigenvectors, evolve them with $\hat{U}(t)$ -> calculate the inner product?

If the $c_i(t)$ are the components with respect to $|i(t)>$, and  the $|i(t)\rangle$ are eigenvectors of $\hat{A}(t)$, then for the measurement of $\hat{A}(t)$ the phase of the $c_i(t)$ doesn't play a role. $\langle \hat{A} \rangle = \sum_i |c_i(t)|^2 A_i$, the phase doesn't enter.
If you'd keep the basis $|i(t)>$ fixed and change the phases of the $c_i(t)$, then you will get a different state, and other measurements will differ. But that is not what's happening here: The state stays the same, but you have freedom in the phase of the $|i(t)\rangle$ and hence also in the phase of the $c_i(t)$

@JoelJärnefelt Yes to your second question - But if $\hat{U}(t)$ is the time evolution of the state in the schroedinger picture, then it should be $\hat{U}^{\dagger}$ that the basis states evolve with.
I can however emphasize again, that this is an abitrary choice. It isn't more motivated than solving the Heisenberg equations of motion, finding the eigenvectors of $\hat{A}(t)$ and developing $\Psi_0\rangle$ in this basis.

Change from the Schroedinger picture to the Heisenberg is not like a coordinate transformation, which leaves vector the same, and only changes its coordinates (components wrt some basis vectors). Instead, we go from one vector $|\psi_S(t)\rangle$(dependent on time) to a different vector $|\psi_H\rangle$ (constant in time), with components that can be either constant in time, or change in time, depending on the basis used.

For time-independent Hamiltonians, the Heisenberg picture transfers time-dependence from wave functions to operators almost by definition; explicitly, Heisenberg-type states need to be constant in order for expectation values (i.e. measurement statistics) to be consistent with those in the Schroedinger picture:
\begin{align*}
\langle\psi_H|\mathcal O_H|\phi_H\rangle &= \langle\psi_H|e^{iH_St/\hbar}\mathcal O_S e^{-iH_St/\hbar}|\phi_H\rangle = \langle \psi_S(t)|\mathcal O_S|\phi_S(t)\rangle
\end{align*}
Heuristically, you can think of it as changing to a reference frame that is "co-moving" with the states.
